# Having a ModuleNotFoundError! in Django

Tags: python, django, modulenotfounderror

i have this project where there is a Login app and there is a Homepage app. The project files look like this

- login

  - homepage

    - models.py
  - login

    - settings.py
    - urls.py
  - usersignup

    - models.py
  - manage.py

Here is usersignup/models.py
'''
from django.db import models

```
class UserDetail(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=225)
    middle_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    email = models.EmailField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.first_name

class WebDetail(UserDetail):
    # user = models.OneToOneField(UserDetail, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True,)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

'''

and here is homepage/models.py

'''

```
from django.db import models
from login.usersignup.models import UserDetail



class UploadProfilePicture(models.Model):
    caption = models.CharField(max_length=2000)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/')


class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(UserDetail, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

'''

and when i run
'''

```
python manage.py check
```

'''
i get this error

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\user\Documents\McDonald\Login\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 401,
in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\user\Documents\McDonald\Login\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 377,
in execute
    django.setup()
  File "C:\Users\user\Documents\McDonald\Login\venv\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Users\user\Documents\McDonald\Login\venv\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 114, in populate

    app_config.import_models()
  File "C:\Users\user\Documents\McDonald\Login\venv\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 211, in import_mod
els
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_modul
e
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\user\Documents\McDonald\Login\login\homepage\models.py", line 2, in <module>
    from login.usersignup.models import UserDetail
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'login.usersignup'
```

so, is there any way i could import the UserDetail class in the usersignup/models to the homepage/models?

Thanks for your contribution

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using :

```
from login.usersignup.models import UserDetail
```

try using this :

```
from usersignup.models import UserDetail
```

Comment: Let me try that